# Change character encoding on a XML Fragment in C#

Tags: c#, xml, character-encoding, xmlreader

I have written the following to read an XML fragement from disk:

```
string fileName = @"C:\test.txt";
XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
settings.ConformanceLevel = ConformanceLevel.Fragment;
using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(fileName, settings))
{
    while (reader.Read())
    { DoSomething(); }
}
```

But it fails when reading special characters like Ö, &, etc. I guess this is something with character encoding. I saw that I can do something like XmlReader.Create(fileName, fileEndoding). However, how do I combine this with the setting of a XMLFragment? My character encoding is ISO8859-1

Comment: If your encoding is ISO-8859-1, the document should state that. Don't fix the reader - fix the document.

Comment: Sorry, fixing the document is not an option.

Comment: I suggest you don't try to use an XmlReader then - it's just not a valid XML document. Is this actually different documents at different times? What's producing them? (You shouldn't have to put up with broken XML. It's *easy* to produce valid XML, and anyone producing broken XML should be shouted at.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:
    new StreamReader(fileName, Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1"))

Comment: Works almost. It fails on this xml element:
   <name>Some & Somemore</name>
Any workarounds for the ampersand???

Comment: XmlReaderSettings.CheckCharacters property?

Comment: Nope, sorry. CheckCharacters to false does not work, changing the xml doc is not an option. Posted this problem as a new question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15044771/c-sharp-xml-fragment-with-an-ampersand