# XML fragment with an ampersand

Tags: c#, xml, streamreader, xmlreader

With a lot of help I worked out the following code:

```
if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(ofd.FileName, Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1")))
    {
        XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
        settings.ConformanceLevel = ConformanceLevel.Fragment;
        using (XmlReader xreader = XmlReader.Create(reader, settings))
        {
            while (xreader.Read())
            {
                DoSomething();
            }
        }
    }
```

I have just one problem left and that is that there is an ampersand in some places in the 'xml document':

```
<name>Me & You</name>
```

I know it's not a valid XML fragment and that the ampersand should be escaped with & however changing the document is not an option in my scenario. Any ideas how I can read this in XML without changing the document? Something with changing the StreamReader maybe?

Comment: Why not just read the document into a `string` and use `String.Relace()`?

Comment: The document are several 100's of MB's.

Comment: @martin Hmm that would be a problem :/

Comment: @Lloyd, I agree, but you might want to put that as an answer so it can be accepted.

Comment: Lol. Funny, but not helpfull.

Comment: @MartijnBurger, Sorry, not intended as funny, I didn't see your response prior to posting.

Comment: None taken. Glad with all help I can get.

Comment: Keep in mind, this is not XML. It only resembles it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inherit from `TextReader` and override the `ReadLine` method to replace the character per line when necessary.  Pass your new stream reader to `XmlReader`, which will never then see the invalid entity.

Edit: although `XmlReader` supports `TextReader`, it does not seem to call the `ReadLine` method... Instead, it looks like we may have to subclass `Stream` directly and work with the `byte[] buffer`.

Edit: the below is what I believe should filter a generic stream and replace ampersand with the encoded entities.  Since it is working with the stream bytes, it does not have any concept of encoding, and therefore assumes ASCII.  It only processes ampersand at the moment, but it should be trivial to encode other entities as well.  It tried it on a 2.5 Gb file and found that it only increased processing time by about 3% and memory load appeared unaffected.  That being said, it is certainly not adequately tested.  I urge you to ensure that the files it produces are identical to the input files with varying buffer sizes.  E.g.:

```
using (var output = File.Open(@"out.xml", FileMode.Create))
using (var input = new AmpersandFilterText(File.Open(@"in.xml", FileMode.Open))
    input.CopyTo(output);
```

then do a binary compare of the files.

Edit #3: I misread the method signature on `TextReader`, `XmlReader` just calls `Read(char[], int, int)`.  Anyway, see below for an implementation which does not depend on character encodings.

```
class TestProgram
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var stringReader = new MemoryStream(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("<name>Me & You</name>"));
        var textReader = new AmpersandFilterText(stringReader);

        XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
        settings.ConformanceLevel = ConformanceLevel.Fragment;
        using (XmlReader xreader = XmlReader.Create(textReader, settings))
        {
            while (xreader.Read())
            {
                Console.WriteLine(xreader.Value);
            }
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

class AmpersandFilterText : StreamReader
{
    public AmpersandFilterText(Stream stream)
        : base(stream)
    {
    }

    private StringBuilder sbBuffer = null;
    private int bufferOffset = 0;

    public override string ReadLine()
    {
        var rawLine = base.ReadLine();
        rawLine = rawLine.Replace("&", "&amp;");
        return rawLine;
    }

    public override int Read()
    {
        char cChar;
        if (sbBuffer != null)
        {
            cChar = sbBuffer[bufferOffset];
            bufferOffset++;
            evalBuffer();
            return cChar;
        }
        else
        {
            cChar = (char)base.Read();
            if (cChar == '&')
                sbBuffer = new StringBuilder("amp;");
            return cChar;
        }
    }

    public override int Read(char[] buffer, int index, int count)
    {
        int destOffset = 0;
        const string replacement = "&amp;";

        //exhaust our buffer first
        if (sbBuffer != null)
        {
            int bufferedToConsume = Math.Min(count, sbBuffer.Length - bufferOffset);
            sbBuffer.CopyTo(bufferOffset, buffer, index, bufferedToConsume);
            destOffset += bufferedToConsume;
            bufferOffset += bufferedToConsume;
            evalBuffer();
        }

        //then, if needed, read more data
        if (destOffset < count)
        {
            char[] newBuffer = new char[count - destOffset];
            var newRead = base.Read(newBuffer, 0, newBuffer.Length);

            //process new data and return directly
            int sourceOffset = 0;
            while (sourceOffset < newRead && destOffset < count)
            {
                char tChar = newBuffer[sourceOffset];
                if (tChar == '&')
                {
                    int replacementOffset = 0;
                    while (replacementOffset < replacement.Length && destOffset < count)
                    {
                        buffer[destOffset + index] = replacement[replacementOffset];
                        destOffset++;
                        replacementOffset++;
                    }

                    sourceOffset++;

                    //we did not copy the entire replacement
                    if (replacementOffset < replacement.Length)
                    {
                        //put the remainder in next time
                        sbBuffer = new StringBuilder();
                        sbBuffer.Append(replacement, replacementOffset, replacement.Length - replacementOffset);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    buffer[destOffset + index] = tChar;
                    destOffset++;
                    sourceOffset++;
                }
            }

            //we have unused data
            if (sourceOffset < newRead)
            {
                if (sbBuffer == null)
                    sbBuffer = new StringBuilder();

                //add data after replace
                for (; sourceOffset < newRead; sourceOffset++)
                {
                    char tChar = newBuffer[sourceOffset];
                    if (tChar == '&')
                        sbBuffer.Append(replacement);
                    else
                        sbBuffer.Append(tChar);
                }
            }
        }

        return destOffset;
    }

    public override int ReadBlock(char[] buffer, int index, int count)
    {
        return this.Read(buffer, index, count);
    }

    public override int Peek()
    {
        if (sbBuffer != null)
            return sbBuffer[bufferOffset];

        return base.Peek();
    }

    public override string ReadToEnd()
    {
        string cLine;
        StringBuilder sbTemp = new StringBuilder();
        while ((cLine = this.ReadLine()) != null)
            sbTemp.AppendLine(cLine);
        return sbTemp.ToString();
    }

    private void evalBuffer()
    {
        if (bufferOffset == sbBuffer.Length)
        {
            //TODO: check perf on sbBuffer.Clear
            sbBuffer = null;
            bufferOffset = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I was thinking along those lines, however my C# experience is one week now. Can you help me out with a code sample? StreamReader inherits from TextReader??

Comment: Hi Mitch, looks very good. Just lost the character encoding now, which gives another error on Ö characters etc. Any thoughts where I can add the character encoding?

Comment: If `XMLReader` doesn't call `ReadLine()`, then it has to call some other method, most likely `Read()`, so overriding that should work.

Comment: Okay, got it running including the character encoding. However, somewhere around line 360000 (!) in the xml document characters are lost. :( The xmlreader fails because the <a_somethinga_something> element is not correctly closed, in reality in the file is <a_something></a_something>. Bummer. :(

Comment: I notice that it is about 10 lines below the first ampersand in the xml document. This cannot be a coïncidence!

Comment: No it's not a coincidence. The AmpersandFilter class crashes somewhere after around 1K characters has been read after the first ampersand is found in the document. Can't figure out why... Anyone???

Comment: @MartijnBurger, you could have changed the original version to work with UCS-2 with relative ease (just insert null bytes inbetween the replacement characters), but making it work with UTF8 would have been difficult.  I have updated the answer with a more flexible class which does not manipulate the raw data directly.